# edit field file on user entity from FosUserBundle

Tags: file, symfony, photo, fosuserbundle

I have User Entity

User.php

```
namespace Back\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\SecureRandom;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     */
    private $first_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     */
    private $last_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     */
    private $genre;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     *
     */
    private $date_naissance;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     */
    private $pays;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="datetime") */
    private $dateinscription;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->dateinscription = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->last_name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $last_name
     */
    public function setLastName($last_name)
    {
        $this->last_name = $last_name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getGenre()
    {
        return $this->genre;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $genre
     */
    public function setGenre($genre)
    {
        $this->genre = $genre;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->first_name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $first_name
     */
    public function setFirstName($first_name)
    {
        $this->first_name = $first_name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPays()
    {
        return $this->pays;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $pays
     */
    public function setPays($pays)
    {
        $this->pays = $pays;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDateNaissance()
    {
        return $this->date_naissance;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $date_naissance
     */
    public function setDateNaissance($date_naissance)
    {
        $this->date_naissance = $date_naissance;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDateinscription()
    {
        return $this->dateinscription;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $dateinscription
     */
    public function setDateinscription($dateinscription)
    {
        $this->dateinscription = $dateinscription;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $file;

    private $temp;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $path
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }
    /**
     * @param mixed $path
     */
    public function setNullPath()
    {
        $this->path = NULL;
    }


    /**
     * Get root directory for file uploads
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getUploadRootDir($type='profilePicture') {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded
        // documents should be saved
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir($type);
    }

    /**
     * Specifies where in the /web directory profile pic uploads are stored
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getUploadDir($type='profilePicture') {
        // the type param is to change these methods at a later date for more file uploads
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
        // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/user/profilepics';
    }

    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        // check if we have an old image path
        if (is_file($this->getAbsolutePath())) {
            // store the old name to delete after the update
            $this->temp = $this->getAbsolutePath();
        } else {
            $this->path = NULL;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
            $this->path = $this->getFile()->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        // check if we have an old image
        if (isset($this->temp)) {
            // delete the old image
            unlink($this->temp);
            // clear the temp image path
            $this->temp = null;
        }

        // you must throw an exception here if the file cannot be moved
        // so that the entity is not persisted to the database
        // which the UploadedFile move() method does
        $this->getFile()->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->id.'.'.$this->getFile()->guessExtension()
        );

        $this->setFile(null);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove()
     */
    public function storeFilenameForRemove()
    {
        $this->temp = $this->getAbsolutePath();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        if (isset($this->temp)) {
            unlink($this->temp);
        }
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath()
    {
        return null === $this->path
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->path;
    }
    public function removeFile()
    {
        $tmp = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->path;
        unlink($tmp);
    }


}
```

In Controller I have

```
public function deleteAction($id)
{
    $em= $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $pers= $em->getRepository('BackUserBundle:User')->find($id);
    $tmp = $pers->getFile();
    if($tmp != NULL)
    {
        $pers->removeFile();
        $pers->setFile();
        $em->persist($pers);
        $em->flush();
    }


    return new RedirectResponse($this->get('router')->generate('fos_user_profile_show'));
}
```

And it's work correctly and it deletes the file and clear the path  field .

My problem now is to make a function to change the path field and the file.

Is there someone to help me
and Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have almost everything you need i think, follow the official doc :

http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

in your controller :

```
public function uploadAction()
{
    $user= new User();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('file')
        ->getForm()
    ;

    if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $user->upload();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(...));
        }
    }

    return array('form' => $form->createView());
}
```

You must change your upload function in the entity a bit to save the path of the file after you move it.

## User.php

```
$this->getFile()->move(
    $this->getUploadRootDir(),
    $this->id.'.'.$this->getFile()->guessExtension()
);
$this->path = $this->getUploadRootDir(),
    $this->id.'.'.$this->getFile()->guessExtension();
```

and don't forget the routing for the upload action.